# How to match line-break in c++ regex?

Tags: c++, regex

I tried the following regex:

```
const static char * regex_string = "([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*";

void find_first(const std::string str);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
        find_first("0s7fg9078dfg09d78fg097dsfg7sdg\r\nfdfgdfg");
}
void find_first(const std::string str)
{
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
        std::regex rgx(regex_string);
        std::smatch matcher;
        if(std::regex_match(str, matcher, rgx))
        {
                std::cout << "Found : " << matcher.str(0) << std::endl;
        } else {
                std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
        }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a557ab3dc5a4897)**

I expected the regex will be completely correct and the group will be found. But it wasn't. Why? How can I match the line-break in c++ regex? In Java it works fine.

Comment: It's `$` in the regular expression IIRC.

Comment: Have you tried to match `(.|\r\n)*` instead of `.*`?

Comment: Using defaults it seems that boost::regex does match '\r' when using '.' (except when using match_not_dot_newline) but std::regex not. So far I cannot see a possibility in std to turn this behavior on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [dot in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) usually matches any character other than a newline [std::ECMAScript syntax](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/).

> `.`   not newline   any character except line terminators (LF, CR, LS, PS).

```
0s7fg9078dfg09d78fg097dsfg7sdg\r\nfdfgdfg
[a-zA-Z0-9]+ matches until \r ↑___↑ .* would match from here
```

In many regex flavors there is a *dotall* flag available to make the dot also match newlines.

If not, there are workarounds in different languages such as `[^]` *not nothing* or `[\S\s]` any whitespace or non-whitespace together in a class wich results in any character including `\n`

```
regex_string = "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[\\S\\s]*";
```

Or use optional line breaks: `([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*(?:\\r?\\n.*)*` or  `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:.|\\r?\\n)*`

[See your updated demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee472c028ab70db7)

---

**Update** - Another idea worth mentioning: [`std::regex::extended`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04)

> A <period> ( '.' ), when used outside a bracket expression, is an ERE that shall match any character in the supported character set except NUL.

```
std::regex rgx(regex_string, std::regex::extended);
```

[See this demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##jVDLTsMwELz7K1bmEoekyi1NWipx4cgHQFFk@VVLrVPZblWB@u3BDikJqBVYlte7szP7YPt9rhjrujtt2PbABSx167wVdLdCY8wKJU4rhFhrnAfnqdcM2IZaSKHHmsDRRsED4OSV5u@P@UuRV2/3ZJbiBULHVnOQ2vBGaut8ctHhdT0QgyEhURsPO6pNEj/UKpYNZdLoHQn6QDCciRwuXClVVZRzLlVR8XIeTcmdVKXjam3XRgYkXByKnP/ZzqRWD7H24GG5jNiXCTFh@HbxM63fB1h1SqabySZgoJ18YApOfnHdjnq2gf4VdgS1TEZ608MhYLNLZhbrEfKdP3Z@dQL81B4Mhxpw9AaNWRBMCnJjtDOIrRN/Cj@3HmQUx7d00LnrPgE)

Comment: `In many regex flavors there is a dotall flag available to make the dot also match newlines`, question is about C++, so it would be helpful if the answer mentioned if there is `/s` modifier available in c++

Comment: @PavelP Right, I wrote it like this because I couldn't find any *dotall flag* in C++. If anyone knows, if there exists a dotall flag in C++ and how to use it, please comment, edit or put new answer.

Comment: btw using std::regex::extended takes away the possibility to use lazy quantifiers

Answer (score 5):

You may try `const static char * regex_string = "((.|\r\n)*)";`
I hope It will help you.

Comment: you would have to escape the '\' chars

Comment: hmm, Use \\ instead of \ chars.

Comment: Or use a raw string `R"(((.|\r\n)*))"`

Answer (score 1):

I am using CTest and PROPERTIES PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION.

[\S\s]* did not work, but (.|\r|\n)* did.

This regex:

```
Function registered for ID 2 was called(.|\r|\n)*PASS
```

Matches:

```
Running test function: RegisterThreeDiffItemsTest04
ID 2 registered for callback
ID 4 registered for callback
ID 11 registered for callback
Function registered for ID 2 was called
ID 2 callback deregistered
ID 4 callback deregistered
ID 11 callback deregistered
Setup: PASS
```

Note: CMakeLists.txt needs to escape the backslashes:

```
SET (ANDPASS "(.|\\r|\\n)*PASS")
```